# Any issues in WordPress 5?

Tags: wordpress

WordPress 5 has recently come out. I've done an upgrade on a test Civi 5.8.0 site on PHP 7.1 and it went through OK and no problems are showing immediately. Is anyone seeing any issues?

It looks like my custom extension and WordPress plugin are working OK.

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the Block editor no longer breaks CiviCRM shortcodes. But you do lose the quick CiviCRM shortcode button.

The classic editor plugin with Wordpress 5.0 makes the move easier. Personally we set the Classic Editor as default and allow users to switch to block with the understanding that they will have to generate the shortcode for civi elsewhere or memorize the shortcode params. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can't get CiviCRM shortcodes to work if the Simple Facebook Connect plugin is active.

Comment: Is this related to 5?

Comment: Probably (I think); I didn't have the problem until after I upgraded to 5.