# Is Civi compatible with Wordpress5.0? *SOLVED*

Tags: wordpress

We just upgraded from WordPress 4.9 to 5.0 and right away Civi 5.2 disappeared.  Is there something in WordPress 5.0 that prevents Civi from operating?  The most current download for Civi says WordPress 3x to 4x.

****SOLVED****

Comment: Is CiviCRM still listed as a plugin in the plugin menu and are you abale to access civicrm content?  It could just be that the link is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

****SOLVED****

The issue is caused by the Civi-Calendar extension. I have contacted the developers about it and asked them to upgrade their extension to make it compatible with civi 5.8. The below files caused specific problems and were disabled.

**public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom/custom_php/CRM/Core/SelectValues.php**

*Breaks the Add Relationships function. 
Breaks the search box on the top left corner.*

**public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom/custom_php/CRM/Core/Event/BAO/Event.php**

*Breaks page: Events > Manage Events Result Error 500*

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked a few days ago but they indicated it worked with a more recent version of civi. You might need to upgrade. See [Any issues in WordPress 5?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27637/any-issues-in-wordpress-5)